# Evaluating all nested generators in Python

Tags: python, generator

I can make a nested group of iterators using a recursive function like this:

```
def rprint(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print('n = %d' % n)
        yield rprint(n-1)
```

Then for a simple example I can evaluate the nested generators manually.

```
>>> p3 = rprint(3)
>>> p3
<generator object rprint at 0x1043b7048>
>>> p2_0 = next(p3)
>>> p2_1 = next(p3)
>>> p2_2 = next(p3)
n = 3
n = 3
n = 3
>>> next(p3) # will raise an error
StopIteration
>>> p1_0_0 = next(p2_0)
>>> p1_0_1 = next(p2_0)
n = 2
n = 2
>>> next(p2_0)# will raise an error
StopIteration
>>> p0_0_0_0 = next(p1_0_0)
n = 1
>>> next(p1_0_0)# will raise an error
StopIteration
>>> p0_0_1_0 = next(p1_0_1)
n = 1
>>> next(p1_0_1)# will raise an error
StopIteration
```

and this goes on as follows ...

```
>>> p1_1_0 = next(p2_1)
>>> p1_1_1 = next(p2_1)
n = 2
n = 2
>>> next(p2_1)# will raise an error
StopIteration
```

... etc.

How can I do this in an automated way for any value of `n` in `rprint`? **I am not interested in making variable references to the intermediate generators** (as I did in the example to illustrate the objects structure).

Comment: I don't believe your in and output is correct.

Comment: Sorry it's fixed now

Comment: Is the order in which to exhaust the generators important?

Comment: No @PaulPanzer I don't care about order in my actual use case

Comment: You say "intermediate generators". Does your actual use case involve the subgenerators eventually yielding something that *isn't* a generator? That never happens here; "flattening" these generators recursively into a non-nested generator just produces an empty generator that `print`s a whole bunch before reporting that it's empty.

Comment: @user2357112 my final result is not important, I just modify an object that is global to the scope of the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure that's what you want but the following code flattens your nested generator:

```
def rprint(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print('n = %d' % n)
        yield rprint(n-1)

def flatten(nested):
    for j in nested:
        if hasattr(j, '__iter__') or hasattr(j, '__getitem__'):
            yield from flatten(j)
        else:
            yield j

list(flatten(rprint(3)))
```

prints:

```
# n = 3
# n = 2
# n = 1
# n = 2
# n = 1
# n = 3
# n = 2
# n = 1
# n = 2
# n = 1
# n = 3
# n = 2
# n = 1
# n = 2
# n = 1
```

Comment: Note that this produces a different output order from the order in the question.

Answer (score 5):

While you *can* do that, using generators purely for side effects this way is a really weird thing to do, and you may want to reconsider your design. That said:

```
def do_the_thing_you_want(generator):
    # Call list on the generator to force all side effects before running
    # subgenerators, as done in the question.
    for subgenerator in list(generator):
        do_the_thing_you_want(subgenerator)
```

Comment: Yeah I am probably going down a crappy path to accomplish what I want. I am using recursion to traverse a nested tree and want to return multiple times for each function call (i.e. the recursive return is in a loop). The way I decided I could do this was by yielding the recursion function inside the loop. And hence where this question came from

Comment: @AlexG: That sounds like you should consider rewriting your original generator to use `yield from` instead of `yield`. `yield from` is Python's mechanism for writing recursive generators, as well as for any case where one generator should delegate to another.

Comment: Alternatively, it might not actually make sense to have generators at all. Why do you say you want to return multiple times for each call? Why do you want to return at all?

Comment: Yes. Just pure yes. Your `yield from` suggestion is great because then I just call `next(rprint(3))` and bam - problem solved. But your second suggestion is the real winner. Thank you. I am dumb :)

Answer (score 3):

By recursively flattening your generators "depth first":

```
def flatten(nested):
    for sublist in nested:
        for element in flatten(sublist):
            yield element
```

yields

```
n = 3
n = 2
n = 1
n = 2
n = 1
n = 3
n = 2
n = 1
n = 2
n = 1
n = 3
n = 2
n = 1
n = 2
n = 1
```

Comment: Note that this produces a different output order from the order in the question.

Comment: Yes, order of execution vs memory consumption is a tradeoff to make. OP said in comments that order of execution does not matter though.